# TCL: Grouping tunnel message together by date day and tunnel

Tags: logging, tcl, cisco

Hi I'm pretty new to TCL coding and wrote this script with the help of this site. I was wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to write this?

```
set y [read -nonewline [set f [open "tmp.txt" r]]];


array set counts [list];
foreach message [split $y "\n"] {
        # This gets the status, ie: DOWN/UP/OFFLINE.
        set status [lindex [split $message] end]; # will assign last field
        set mon [lindex [split $message] 1]; # number represents the filed number
        set day [lindex lindex[split $message] 2];
        if {$day ==""} {
            set day [lindex [split $message] 3];
        } else {
            set day [lindex [split $message] 2]
        }
    # +number represents the counter
        if {[info exists counts($mon,$day,$status)]} {
                set counts($mon,$day,$status) [expr {$counts($mon,$day,$status)+1}] 
        } else {
                set counts($mon,$day,$status) 1
        }   
}

# sort based for down type evetns
puts "\n\nTabl: Down per day"
puts "\n\n MMM DD || Cnt Status"
puts " ====================="

foreach count [lsort -increasing -unique [array names counts]] {
        foreach {mon day status} [split $count ","] { break; }
        if {$status =="down"} {
            puts " $mon $day || [set counts($count)] \t $status"
        }

    }
# process tunnels that are down and flapped 3 times

array set countsT [list];
foreach message [split $y "\n"] {
        # This gets the status, ie: DOWN/UP/OFFLINE.
        set status [lindex [split $message] end];
        set mon [lindex [split $message] 1];
        set day [lindex [split $message] 2];
        set Tunnx [lindex [split $message] 9];

        if {$day ==""} {
            set day [lindex [split $message] 3];
            set Tunnx [lindex [split $message] 10]
        } else {
            set day [lindex [split $message] 2]
        }

        if {[info exists countsT($mon,$day,$Tunnx,$status)]} {
            set countsT($mon,$day,$Tunnx,$status) [expr {$countsT($mon,$day,$Tunnx,$status)+1}]
        } else {
                set countsT($mon,$day,$Tunnx,$status) 1
        }
}

puts "\n\nTabl: Tunnel = Flap >3"
puts "\n\n MMM DD || Tunnelx\tCnt\t Status"
puts " ================================="

foreach count [lsort -increasing -unique [array names countsT]] {

        if {[set countsT($count)] < 2} { continue; } {
            foreach {mon day tun n status} [split $count ","] { break; } 
            if {$status =="down"} {
                puts " $mon $day || $tun \t [set countsT($count)] \t$status"
        }
    }
}
if {[info exists f]} { close $f }
```

Sample log:

```
670555: Mar  9 23:39:18.214: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel1, changed state to down
670557: Mar  9 23:39:50.877: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670559: Mar  9 23:41:08.662: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel4, changed state to down
670561: Mar  9 23:41:18.309: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel3, changed state to down
670562: Mar  9 23:43:13.237: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670564: Mar  9 23:45:26.549: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670567: Mar  9 23:46:45.708: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel3, changed state to down
670570: Mar  9 23:49:31.222: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670574: Mar  9 23:53:14.295: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670576: Mar  9 23:55:49.217: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670577: Mar  9 23:56:16.180: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel1, changed state to down
670581: Mar  9 23:56:45.480: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel3, changed state     to down
670583: Mar  9 23:59:54.080: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670585: Mar 10 00:00:33.224: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel1, changed state to down
670587: Mar 10 00:04:03.292: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670589: Mar 10 00:04:38.921: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel3, changed state to down
670590: Mar 10 00:05:00.505: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel1, changed state to down
670593: Mar 10 00:06:22.473: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670596: Mar 10 00:09:07.262: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel1, changed state to down
670598: Mar 10 00:11:11.294: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down
670602: Mar 10 00:14:23.649: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel1, changed state to down
670604: Mar 10 00:14:59.296: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Tunnel2, changed state to down


 Results:

 Tabl: Down per day


 MMM DD || Cnt Status
 =====================
 Mar 10 || 9     down
 Mar 9 || 13     down


 Tabl: Tunnel = Flap >3


  MMM DD || Tunnelx      Cnt      Status
  =================================
  Mar 10 || Tunnel1       4      down
  Mar 10 || Tunnel2       4      down
  Mar 9 || Tunnel1        2      down
  Mar 9 || Tunnel2        7      down
  Mar 9 || Tunnel3        3      down
```

**UPDATE:**

Required to record the amount of tunnels that flapped over the day.

Using the table below for a data reference the new table would be Mar 10 2 tunnels that flapped and Mar 9th  3 tunnels.

I can't see how to work out the additional grouping of tunnelx field to count number flapped tunnels.

```
  MMM DD || Tunnelx      Cnt      Status
  =================================
  Mar 10 || Tunnel1       4      down
  Mar 10 || Tunnel2       4      down
  Mar 9 || Tunnel1        2      down
  Mar 9 || Tunnel2        7      down
  Mar 9 || Tunnel3        3      down
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- you don't have to loop through the file twice, just accumulate the arrays in the first loop
- the idiomatic way to read a file line by line is with `while {[gets ...` as I've shown
- as you've seen, `split` only splits on a single whitespace char. I've demonstrated using `regexp` to collect the fields.

I'd do this:

```
array set counts [list]
array set countsT [list]

set f [open tmp.txt r]

while {[gets $f message] != -1} {
    set fields [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $message]
    set mon [lindex $fields 1] 

    # use day "09" instead of "9" so it gets the sorting right.
    set day [format %02d [lindex $fields 2]]

    # have to be careful to remove the trailing comma from the tunnel
    set Tunnx [string trimright [lindex $fields 9] ,]

    set status [lindex $fields end] ;# will assign last field

    incr counts($mon,$day,$status) 
    incr countsT($mon,$day,$Tunnx,$status) 
}

close $f


# sort based for down type evetns
puts "\n\nTabl: Down per day"
puts "\n\n MMM DD || Cnt Status"
puts " ====================="

# don't need "-unique" flag: array keys will be unique
foreach count [lsort -increasing [array names counts]] {
    foreach {mon day status} [split $count ","] { break }
    if {$status eq "down"} {
        puts [format "%s %s || %3d\t%s" $mon $day $counts($count) $status]
    }
}

puts "\n\nTabl: Tunnel = Flap >3"
puts "\n\n MMM DD || Tunnelx\tCnt\t Status"
puts " ================================="

foreach count [lsort -increasing [array names countsT]] {
    if {$countsT($count) < 2} { continue } 
    foreach {mon day tun status} [split $count ","] { break } 
    if {$status eq "down"} {
        puts [format " %s %s || %s\t%3d\t%s" $mon $day $tun $countsT($count) $status]
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that incr works on uninitialized var, which simplifies the code logic quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm testing the code on a win8 running tcl 8.5. I get this error.  MMM DD || Cnt Status
 =====================
expected integer but got "09"
    while executing
"format "%s %d || %3d\t%s" $mon $day $counts($count) $status"
    ("foreach" body line 4)
    invoked from within
"foreach count [lsort -increasing [array names counts]] {
    foreach {mon day status} [split $count ","] { break }
    if {$status eq "down"} {
      ..."
    (file "t4.3.tcl" line 44)

Comment: That looks like the classic Tcl Invalid Octal Number problem.  Tcl 8.5 interprets a number starting with 0 as an Octal number and 09 isn't a valid Octal number.  See here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/498 for lots of details and fixes.

Comment: its been awhile but I need some new assistance. How would I group the number of tunnel flaps in a day i.e. Mar 01 Tunnel 2 flapped twice but its only record as once.. see question for update

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about "better", but I would like to suggest several changes:

```
set f [open "tmp.txt" r]
set contents [read -nonewline $f]
close $f

array set status_counts {}
array set tunnel_counts {}

foreach message [split $contents "\n"] {
    set mon    [lindex $message 1]
    set day    [lindex $message 2]
    set tunnel [lindex $message 9]
    set status [lindex $message end]

    # Do we really need this block?
    if {$day ==""} {
        set day [lindex $message 3]
        set tunnel [lindex $message 10]
    } else {
        set day [lindex $message 2]
    }

    set index "$mon,$day,$status"
    if {[info exists status_counts($index)]} {
        set status_counts($index) [expr {$status_counts($index)+1}] 
    } else {
        set status_counts($index) 1
    }   

    set index "$mon,$day,$tunnel,$status"
    if {[info exists tunnel_counts($index)]} {
        set tunnel_counts($index) [expr {$tunnel_counts($index)+1}]
    } else {
        set tunnel_counts($index) 1
    }
}

# sort based for down type evetns
puts "\n\nTabl: Down per day"
puts "\n\n"
puts [format "%-3s %2s || %3s %s" MMM DD Cnt Status]
puts [format "%-3s %2s || %3s %s" === == === ======]

foreach count [lsort -increasing -unique [array names status_counts *,down]] {
    foreach {mon day status} [split $count ","] { break }
    puts [format "%-3s %2s || %3s %s" $mon $day $status_counts($count) $status]
}

puts "\n\nTabl: Tunnel = Flap >3"
puts "\n\n"
puts [format "%-3s %2s || %-8s %-4s %s" MMM DD TunnelX Cnt Status]
puts [format "%-3s %2s || %-8s %-4s %s" === == ======= === ======]

foreach count [lsort -increasing -unique [array names tunnel_counts *,down]] {
    if {[set tunnel_counts($count)] < 2} { continue; } 
    foreach {mon day tun n status} [split $count ","] { break } 
    puts [format "%-3s %2s || %-8s %-4s %s" $mon $day $tun $tunnel_counts($count) $status]
}
```

#### Discussions

The following are the changes I made and my thoughts behind them. These are my opinion, as such you may or may not agree with me.

1. Tcl does not require ending a line with semicolon, so I rather not see them, which helps the code's clarity.
2. Open and read a file as two separate steps. In case of error, I know which step causes the trouble, thus make it easier to debug.
3. I prefer to close a file as soon as I am done, instead of at the end of the script.
4. Combine two loops into one. You had two loops, each carries similar, but slightly different steps. I combine them into one loop, which reduces the amount of code, complexity, and chance of error.
5. I prefer identifiers name spelled out, not abbreviated. For example, I prefer *tunnel_counts* over *countsT*
6. There is no need to split the message before calling `lindex`. In most cases, Tcl treats a string and list the same way. That means a string can act as a list, with items separated by spaces.
7. In the first loop, I don't understand the block of code that test for `$day == ""`, so I just leave that block alone. I suspect that you won't need it.
8. I introduced the variable `index`, which reduce typing, making the code cleaner, and reduce the chance of making errors.
9. Instead of testing for `$status == "down"` within the two reporting loop, I applied filters to the `array names` command: `[array names tunnel_counts *,down]`. This eliminates the `if` statements within these loops.
10. Formatting changes to better alignment
11. Finally, the original code's indentation is not consistent: sometimes you indent with 4 spaces, other times with 8. It might have to do with how you set tabs within your editor.
12. It is important to note, your original script works just fine. The changes I suggests are for ease of reading, understanding, and maintenance.

Comment: Nice use of the glob pattern for `array names`.

Comment: Kudos for the feedback. Point 11 was my fault on the question, I still cant work out how to properly indent a block of code when posting questions.

Comment: FYI. When posting, I just indent all of my original code by 4 spaces and paste in stackoverflow.